# How to pass string to external function in LLVM Pass?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm, llvm-ir

So I am trying to send the names of functions called through call instructions I find in a program to an external function as a string. So the declaration of my external function is: `void func(string s);` In my LLVM pass I am trying to pass a value to the parameter `s`. I am stuck at adding the function declaration of `func` using `getOrInsertFunction`, here is a code snippet:

```cpp
Function * func;

Constant * funcDec = M.getOrInsertFunction("func",
                                      Type::getVoidTy(M.getContext)), ???);
```

I am confused about what to put in place of `???`.

As an example `Type::getInt32Ty(M.getContext())` is used if the parameter is `int`. I know LLVM doesn't have `std::string`. So how can I achieve passing a string to an external function?

Thanks!

Comment: It would be simpler if you changed the signature to `void func(char *s)`. Then you could just use `i8*` as the type.

Comment: as ismail pointed out char* would be simpler rather the string class  P.S. I always use clang/clang++ for simple testcases to find out llvm-ir of c or c++ code. example: clang++ -S -emit-llvm test.cpp will generate test.ll file with llvm-ir.

Answer (score 1):

String is basically character pointer. Char is 8 bit. So you can put

`Type::getInt8PtrTy(M.getContext())` in place of `???`.